# Cordova UIWebView APIs Deprecated API Usage

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

I am kind of confused because I am still getting the ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage warning when I uploaded on the App Store. I have already upgraded my cordova-ios platform to **version 5.1.1** as well as my the InAppBrowser to version **3.2.0**

Here are my plugin list:

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.2.0 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.1.4 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.1 "Diagnostic"
```

And I have added WKWebViewOnly in the **config.xml**. Here is the config.xml for ios

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="1024" src="res/icon/ios/Icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
</platform>
```

I am not sure what I've got wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check in your xcode console what is loading WkWebwiew or UIWebview.

Comment: can you explain me how to check in xcode, which one is loading?

Comment: App run chesinapudu console lo kanipistadi bro WkWebwiew na leka UIWebview lo open avuthunda ani telustadi.

Comment: Is there any reference screenshot available with you?

Comment: @mepraveenk got it...?

Answer (score 0):

**2 Things here,**

1. Did you upgrade to WKWebView by using

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save

2. **CordovaWebViewEngine** should have the value **CDVWKWebViewEngine**

Comment: Follow this link for proper WKWebView upgrade: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/wkwebview/

Comment: I'm not using Ionic. So this is the plugin I used **https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine  version  1.1.4**

Comment: I've upgraded to **1.2.1** and tried to run the app but it's now stuck on the splash screen

Comment: Oh Okay, make sure you install wkwebview plugin from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, as I mentioned CordovaWebViewEngine should use CDVWKWebViewEngine to utilise wkwebview engine.

Comment: Already changes the value to **CDVWKWebViewEngine** but it's not working anymore. Now stuck on the splashscreen :(

Comment: After making these changes in config xml, did you try removing and adding iOS platform again?

Comment: I have already changed the value to **CDVWKWebViewEngine**. And yes, I have also tried removing and adding the iOS platform multiple time, but it's not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the **inappbrowser plugin** you may need to update it to the latest.